# Textmate equivalent of VIM's ci (change inside)?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

Does anyone know a textmate equivalent of VIM's ci (change inside) command? I like this VIM feature but generally prefer TextMate. I'd like to be able to do things like change inside quotes or parens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have Edit > Select > Enclosing Brackets.

There is an "[experimental.tmbundle](https://github.com/textmate/experimental.tmbundle)" that provides a sort-of-similar feature called "Balance Jr".

It's only equivalent to `vi<something>`: if you are somewhere between a pair of `()` it will work like `vi(` or like `vi"` if you are between a pair of `""`.

If I remember correctly it was very buggy, illogical and unpredictable and didn't work well with long strings or many spaces.

Vim's text-objects are very precise, if you are between a pair of `""` enclosed by a pair of `()` you can select/delete/yank/shange exactly what you want. In a similar situation in TextMate, you are stuck and you must resort to a lot of `<Right><Right><Right><Left><Left>`.

Comment: Cool. That's helpful. Select Enclosing Brackets (shift+cmd+b) is not exactly what I want but it's pretty close and I didn't know about it until reading this. Thanks!

Comment: Poking around and also noticed Select Current Scope (control+opt+b) which is actually closer to VIM's ci command. It will select everything within your current scope (e.g. a string, parans, etc). Hit the combo again and you'll step outward in scope expanding your selection.

Comment: @Cory Shires -- Yes, it's in the same menu, I think. Looking at the menus of a new app is usually the first thing I do. It gives me a pretty good idea of what it can do very quicly. Doing the same when trying to solve a problem or shortening a boring task is also useful, sometimes. That's how I discovered the combo to add text at the end of a bunch of lines, for example. TextMate is a very good app, quite a lot of power but it doesn't show off: curiosity is king.